# Changing frames of JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm facing a problem I can't manage to solve.

I imported `JSQMessages` to my projet and put it into my `viewController` which have a `UIView` with an `UIImage` inside on top acting like a `Navigation Bar`. I also have a `tabBar` but when I push my segue, everything disappears to get the normal `JSQMessagesViewController` view.

What I want is the `JSQMessagesViewController` frames to let my top and bot bar visible. I tried changing the `constraints` of the `collectionView` from `JSQMessagesViewController` nib but it did not success.

Is there a way to do it ? I am kinda news to constraints and stuff but I do think I did it good, if someone could help me with it.

Trying Abhay Singh Naurang solution, I did wrote:

```
class SendNewMessageViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let messageView = JSQMessagesViewController()
    messageView.senderId = "test"
    messageView.senderDisplayName = "bryan"
    let navigationBarHeight = 66
    let bottomTabBarHeight = 44
    messageView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(navigationBarHeight), self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - CGFloat(bottomTabBarHeight) - CGFloat(navigationBarHeight));
    self.view.addSubview(messageView.view)
}
```

The frame seems correct but I still lose my `tabBar` (meaning it juste disapears, the square from `tabBar`goes white, the keyboard does not seem to respond and the `textField` doesnt move according to the keyboard sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to create instance of JSQMessagesViewController on a viewcontroller on which you can add JSQMessagesViewController view on that and you can set frame of JSQMessagesViewController view .
 for example you have UserListViewController and you are pushing to ChatViewController so that on ChatViewController will have

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    JSQMessagesViewController *objcMessageVC = [JSQMessagesViewController alloc]init];
    CGFloat navigationBarHeight = 64;
    CGFloat bottomTabBarHeight =40;
    objcMessageVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,64,CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame),CGRectHeight(self.view.frame)-navigationBarHeight-bottomTabBarHeight);
    [self addSubview:objcMessageVC.view];
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I updated my question according to your answer and where I did manage to go from it !